# Google Sheets, cell referencing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I'm using a Google Forms with a checkbox template. To extract results, my current formula is:

```
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(Responses!B17:17&","),","))))
```

I want to drag the formula horizontally, with `B17:17` increasing to `B18:18` instead of `C17:17`. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still looking at modifying your formula in the manner you've requested, but is it possible that the following formula also gives you the result you are aiming for?  Please try it out and let me know.  For testing purposes, I've limited its range; it can be adjusted as needed...

```
=transpose(Responses!B17:Z41)
```

**UPDATE:**

I think the following formula is what you specifically asked for, a formula that could be dragged across.  Please test it out and see if it works on your sheet.  If not please highlight the problem with it in your sheet for us.

```
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
   INDIRECT("'Responses'!B"& COLUMN(Q1) & ":" & COLUMN(Q1))
   & ","),","))))
```

This uses your base formula, but changes the address range to use INDIRECT, and then uses the column values (as it is dragged sideways) to generate the row values of the range it is acting on in Responses.

Note that the column Q was used to generate a starting value of 17, to create the initial B17 address in Responses.  This column letter can be changed, in case you need to start somewhere else in the Responses range.The "Q" is incremented automatically by Sheets as the formula is dragged sideways, which increases the resuslting "row value" pulled from Responses.

Let us know how this works for you.

Results below; your formula in B2 and C2, draggable formula in E2:J2, and simple `TRANSFORM` in L2:
[image]

Comment: this is perfect! a minor thing, because i use checkbox template for my forms, the cells without any responses ends up as ",,,,,". I know i could use ```=IF(ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(Responses3!A63:63&","),","))))=",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,","",ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(Responses3!A63:63&","),",")))))``` (old formula), but is there a cleaner way of removing the commas?

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet, with just some checkboxes and the formula that is giving you the error.  I'm having understanding exactly what you have.  Here is a guide on how best to share:  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/how-to-share-a-google-sheets-demo-spreadsheet/138383#138383

Comment: Can you clarify which formula helped you?  Is there a reason why the plain TRANPOSE didn't do what you needed?  Secondly, is it possible that you can use a REGEXREPLACE to delete the commas, something like: =regexreplace(cell-or-range,"\,","") ?  Inside an ArrayFormula, this could process a whole range...

Comment: `=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
   INDIRECT("'Responses'!B"& COLUMN(Q1) & ":" & COLUMN(Q1))
   & ","),","))))`
This one worked perfectly. as for the commas, if you have checkboxes in the forms it adds commas for each checkbox if there's no response